# Numpy - choosing indices based on a function

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Assuming I have a matrix, and x,y that represents a function (1 y value per each x value).

I'm looking for an efficient way to "choose" only the elements that are above the function.

So, just for the example, lets say I have a 5X5 matrix of all-zeros, and my x,y  are:

```
x   y
0   2
1   3
2   2
3   1
4   2
```

So lets say I want to convert anything above the function to 1, I want the output to be:

```
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,0
1,0,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1
```

I tried playing with fancy indexing, `where` function etc. but still didn't figure out how to do it without a for loop.

EDIT:

Adding a graphical example, assuming I have a matrix (image) and my function (x,y coordinates) is the green line - I need to choose all the places above (or below) this line.

[image: graphical example]

Comment: Please, post your code with the loop.

Comment: It will be easier to understand what you intend to do. Nothing to lose posting your code heh?

Comment: I didn't implement it with a for loop, as I need my code to be fast. If the example I gave was not clear enough I'll write it and add to the question (even though I did my best to be as clear as I can, and I think the example explains what I intend to do).

Comment: Thanks, man. I'll add a graphical description to make it more clear (if still it's not clear enough I'll write a simple for loop, which I don't believe will make it clearer, but I respect your request for that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bit unclear but I think I see what you're going for:

```
if y value <  row value, result's element is 1
if y value >= row value, result's element is 0

x > 0 1 2 3 4
y > 2 3 2 1 2

row   result
v       v
0   0,0,0,0,0
1   0,0,0,0,0
2   0,0,0,1,0
3   1,0,1,1,1
4   1,1,1,1,1
```

Alright then, let's do this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.array([2, 3, 2, 1, 2])

rows = x[:, np.newaxis] # make a column

result = np.where(y < rows, 1, 0)
```

Just in case you need the explanation, `y < rows` made a 5x5 matrix because it broadcasted a `(5,)` array and a `(5, 1)` array. Broadcasting is sort of how NumPy does nested for-loops on arrays:

```
    5  # y
5 x 1  # rows
------
5 x 5  # y < rows

^   ^
Each of these dimensions is equivalent to a level in a nested for-loop.
```